# How do I randomize the individual stats of elements in a list one-by-one in C#?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

How can I randomize the individual stats of random elements in a list in C#?

This is my line of code:

```cs
public void RandomizePeople()
{      
    string path = "Assets/Resources/Texts/MaleFirstNames.txt";

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < StarterPeople.Count; i++)
    {
        StarterPeople[i].itemName = lines[Random.Range(0, lines.Length)];
        StarterPeople[i].Gender = (Random.value > 0.5f);
        StarterPeople[i].Health = (Random.Range(80, 100));
        StarterPeople[i].Stamina = (Random.Range(80, 100));
    }
}
```

It gives me random stats but it gives the same random stat to all elements in the list.

I wanted to randomize the stats of all the individual elements in the list but I don't want all the elements to have the same random stats.

Comment: have you set `Random.InitSeed()` in your app to prevent same values?

Comment: how are you populating your list? if StarterPeople contains reference types is it possible that every element it actually referencing the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

I did not make the stats of individual characters as a prefab in order to edit them properly, instead I made a scriptable object prefab to each character and attached it to it.

However this was causing an issue because when I edited the itemname and health stats, it would change the scriptable object prefab in Unity.

I went ahead and deleted that and just made a script for the stats, attached it to the element on the list with a prefab and it worked.

Thanks for the help yall!

Answer (score 0):

Just trying the following code with nothing, the Random seed never being explicitly initialised.

```C#
void Update()
{
    int iterations = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        var a = Random.Range(80, 100);
        Debug.Log(a);
    }
}
```

Gives totally random outputs.

Notice the Random class was never seeded. It is simply not necessary to do so to get random numbers out of it.

What I think is more likely is that every element of your array is accidently pointing to the same instance.

The following code

```C#
[SerializeField] private ValueClass[] valueClasses = new ValueClass[10];
void Start()
{
    var classInstance = new ValueClass();

    for (var i = 0; i < valueClasses.Length; i++)
    {
        valueClasses[i] = classInstance;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < valueClasses.Length; i++)
    {
        var a = Random.Range(80, 100);
        Debug.Log(a);
        valueClasses[i].value = a;
    }
}
```

Produces this effect

[image]

But the console prints the random numbers, as they are being generated correctly, only overwritten.

[image]

Another alternative would be some weird properties into mutable value types, but it doesn't look like that's what's happening here.